# High-side switch on N-MOSFET for 1-Wire

Tags: mosfet, switches, gate-driving, fet

I have two devices that both control 1-Wire data line:

[image]

The system is designed in a way that only one of devices will be working and another will be in power-off state. When device is turned off it can pull line to ground, so I need to isolate one device from another.

Also, 1-Wire bus is made so, that when data transfer both 1-Wire controller (like MCU, for example) and 1-Wire controlled devices (digital sensors, thermometers etc.), so switch has to be bidirectional when on-state. For that I can use N-channel MOSFET turned in the way, that current from device1/2 can always flow, when line potential is lower that on device, and can flow backwards, only when MOSFET is open.

But to control gate of that MOSFET I do need gate driver. There are high-side switches built on N-Channel MOSFET, that has gate driver inside them, f.e. [TPS22959](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS22959?qgpn=tps22959)

Based on its block diagram:

[image]

And on example from TI [article](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidua64/tidua64.pdf?ts=1698403672177#:%7E:text=1.3%20Back,Current%20Blocking%20Design%20TIDUA64%E2%80%93June%202015):

[image]

I can assume, that it can handle current in both directions, so it is suitable for my purpose.

But I do need more variants, and also I need switch in package with leads, like SOIC/SOT/SOJ/etc

I need some variants from other manufacturers too. But I don't know how do I search them. I've tried 'load switch' and 'power switch', but I found some acceptable only on TI selector. So how do I search for that switch?

Comment: You need Tri-State Buffers instead of mosfets. It does just what you try to do.

Comment: Replace the mosfet circuits with Tri-State Buffers. It does just that. When -OE is low, the data flows through the buffer. When -OE is high, the buffer output (B) is in high impedance state and doesn't interfere with data from other sources. I added a schematic to an answer I posted earlier but someone deleted it. I hope the answer will be shown again.

Comment: @Fredled Tri-State buffers without supply may pull the output low, e.g. via integrated protection diodes.

Comment: Yes. You better provide required current on the Vcc pin and also ground connection. ;)

Comment: Tri-State Buffer will cut MCU port from line on backwards. So when controlled device pulls line to 0, MCU pin voltage still will be high, and data cannot "break through" from controlled device to controller

Comment: Wouldn't a P-MOSFET do the job?

Comment: P-MOSFET is open when poweroff. I've made a custom circuit at last - NMOS+external high-voltage source (I've already had one, but could use charge pump if no)